# Java Comparator: Violates General Contract

Tags: java

So I have this comparator:

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class SolutionComparator implements Comparator<ExpressionTree> {
    private final int target;

    public SolutionComparator(int target) {
        this.target = target;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(ExpressionTree o1, ExpressionTree o2) {
        int v1 = o1.getValue();
        int v2 = o2.getValue();
        if (v1 == -1 && v2 == -1)
            return 0;
        else if (v1 == -1)
            return 1;
        else if (v2 == -1)
            return -1;
        else if (v1 == v2)
            return (int)Math.signum(solutionCost(o1) - solutionCost(o2));
        else
            return (int)Math.signum(Math.abs(target-v1) - Math.abs(target-v2));
    }

    private int solutionCost(ExpressionTree v) {
        int cost = 0;
        Operation o = v.getOperator();
        if (o != Operation.NONE) {
            cost += o.getCost();
            for (ExpressionTree e : v.getChildren())
                cost += solutionCost(e);
        }
        return cost;
    }
}
```

I have been looking at this code for months, and I can't find out why it violates comparator general contract.

The idea is that each ExpressionTree can be evaluated to one result. (the `getValue()` method). If it returns -1, it is always higher than other number. If the value differs, compare to how close it is to `target`. If the value is same, compare by solution cost.

With this comparator Java throws IllegalStatesException. But if I remove cost-based comparison, it works.

---

**EDIT:** Exception Trace

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeHi(TimSort.java:868)
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:485)
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse(TimSort.java:408)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:214)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:173)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:659)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:217)
    at ***.run(***:123)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Can you post the whole exception trace?

Comment: I had the exact same problem here some time ago. This is an equals problem. I will try to remeber what it was and answer you.

Comment: Question updated with exception trace.

Comment: for comparators its generally recommended to write them so that compare(a,b) = -compare(b,a). your comparator probably breaks this for some a,b. a simple O(n^2) loop will find those 2 elements for you and then you could debug your code.

Comment: Can you have subtrees with a -2 or smaller result from solutionCost?

Comment: @radai problem is, there's none.

Comment: The Comparator looks right... you're not modifying `ExpressionTree` while sorting, right?

Comment: @Flavio No, I am sure I am not.

Comment: What values of `int` are we talking about? Comparing with subtraction is ok as long as you do not go over the `int` limits, so if you are using very large values, you might run into trouble.

Comment: @Flavio The final operation cost is at most 1000. v1 and v2 is irrelevant since exception does not triggered if I remove the cost comparison.

Comment: Can you try to replace `(int)Math.signum(solutionCost(o1) - solutionCost(o2))` with `Integer.compare(solutionCost(o1), solutionCost(o2))` and see if anything changes? Everything else looks ok...

Comment: @Flavio No, it doesn't help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `Comparator` violates the transitivity of equality required by [the contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,%20T)):

> Finally, the implementor must ensure that compare(x, y)==0 implies that sgn(compare(x, z))==sgn(compare(y, z)) for all z.

Suppose you have three `ExpressionTree`s `o1, o2, o3` with respective values
`v1, v2, v3`
and solutionCosts
`s1, s2, s3`
such that
`v1 == v2`,
`target - v1 == v3 - target` (so `abs(target-v1) == abs(target-v3)`)
and
`s1 < s2` (so that `compare(o1, o2) == -1`, which can be said `o1 < o2` for simplicity).
Then `o1 == o3` and `o2 == o3` but `o1 < o2`, that is,
`compare(o1, o3) == 0`
but
`sgn(compare(o1, o2)) != sgn(compare(o3, o2))`
since
`sgn(compare(o1, o2)) == -1` and `sgn(compare(o3, o2)) == 0`.

<strike>I'm not sure how you would fix this, but there's the reason for it.</strike>

**Edit:** @Nat (OP) came up with this elegant solution:

> Fix is to replace
>   `if (v1 == v2)`
>   with
>   `if (Math.abs(target-v1) == Math.abs(target-v2))`

Comment: Good catch! I had finally got it too, but you beat me by a few minutes :)

Comment: Thank you very much.

For those who is interested, fix is to replace `if (v1 == v2)` with `if (Math.abs(target-v1) == Math.abs(target-v2))`

Comment: @Flavio Thank you. On a lot of questions, the first answer comes in at like thirty seconds, so I was expecting you to scoop me at any moment.