# Collections.sort not working on java 1.7

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparator

Java 6 uses merge sort to compare two objects in Collections.sort() whereas Java 1.7 uses Timsort

I have this class for object to sort

```
Class ObjectSort 
{
    String Name = "";
    int priority = 0;

    public ObjectSort (String name, int priority)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    public getPriority()
    {
        return priority;
    }
}
```

and my test class is

```
TestClass 
{
     ...main()
    {
      List<ObjectSort> sorted = new ArrayList<ObjectSort> ();
      sorted.add ("Table", 99);
      sorted.add ("Chair", 1);
      Collections.sort(sorted, new Comparator ());
    }

 // inner class to define comparator logic
 private static final class Comparator implements  java.util.Comparator<ObjectSort>
 {
    @Override
    public int compare (ObjectSort f1, ObjectSort f2)
    {
        try
        {
            // Get the allocation priorities
            int priority1 = f1.getPriority ();
            int priority2 = f2.getPriority ();

            if (priority1 == priority2)
                return 0;
            else
                return (priority1 > priority2 ? 1 : 0);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Shouldn't happen, because we have the objects OK and there's no database activity
            // happening here.
            assert true;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}

}
```

Now when we run the code in java 1.6, it sorts it correctly, Chair comes BEFORE table that is it is sorting it is ASCENDING order, which I want.

But where the code is run in Java 1.7, it does not sort it at all, Table comes before Chair. I checked and 1.6 uses merge sort whereas 1.7 is using Timsort. Please help me tell what is wrong in my code ?

UPDATE
In 1.7 in variable f1, Chair comes during code execution whereas in 1.6 Table comes!

Thanks!

Aiden

Comment: Try a debugger. Also, `return Integer.valueOf(priority1).compareTo(priority2);`

Comment: I agree with @ElliottFrisch. Also you could've changed this line to this `return (priority1 > priority2 ? 1 : -1);` Instead of 0 again, return -1.

Comment: but why it is doing it ? Please read UPDATED in the bottom of the question. Is it due to 1.7 version ?

Comment: Step through it with a debugger to understand exactly **why**. But basically yes, merge sort and timsort are different algorithms and they behave differently. As does quicksort and counting sort and selection sort. Why are you surprised that they are not identical? Also, Java 1.7 is already [EOL](https://www.infoq.com/news/2015/05/Oracle-Ends-Java-7Public-Updates) (for almost two years now!) - why are you asking about this behavior?

Comment: @ElliotFrisch  because at client side, the code is breaking, they have updated the java to 1.7 :( and this code is not working there now :( I have to see why it is doing it. Does not the Comparable class I have written has the LOGIC to SORT ANYTHING in ASCENDING order ?

Comment: i am only asking why my logic come out as wrong when java 1.7 is used ? Does it need -1 instead of 0 to return ?

Comment: Well try and see whether it works. Your `compareTo` method is supposed to work that way. Because returning 0 means that 2 things are the same, which in fact they might not be, and the Timsort algorithm  might depend on that to sort properly.

Comment: @Aiden Your comparator does not follow contract, it will sometimes return 1 for a comparison, but it will return 0 for the inverse.

Comment: See [also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20354527/java-comparator-violates-general-contract).

Comment: oh it means I should return -1 instead of 0, which will then sort it correctly. I will give it a try and will then mark this answered if it works!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your comparator is broken. When you have a Comparator

```
comparator.compare(a, b) == -comparator.compare(b, a)
```

The reason Java 7 doesn't accept this is; Java 7 has more checks that this condition is true.

> they have updated the java to 1.7 :( and this code is not working there now :(

It never worked, it probably didn't sort properly before, but you didn't get a runtime error before.

A shorter version which will work is; (Don't reuse the name of common built in classes)

```
static class ObjectSortComparator implements Comparator<ObjectSort> {
    @Override
    public int compare (ObjectSort f1, ObjectSort f2) {
        // Get the allocation priorities
        int priority1 = f1.getPriority ();
        int priority2 = f2.getPriority ();

        return priority1 == priority2 ? 0 : (priority1 > priority2 ? 1 : -1);
    }
}
```

Note: in Java 8 you don't need to write this yourself, you can do

```
sorted.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(ObjectSort::getPriority));
```

Comment: Thanks, then it means I have to use -1 instead of 0 when priority1 is less than priority2 ?

Comment: @Aiden Indeed, I have updated my answer.  I suggest you have a unit test which checks the condition I mentioned above.

Comment: @Aiden Note: you don't need to catch an Exception and ignore it. Better to have it throw the original exception (Though that shouldn't happen either)